# Using variable for column reference in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

First off - I'm totally new to VBA. I'm trying to understand the syntax used to if I want to use a variable for the column header part of a range call. ex:

```
If up <= Range("Table4[*variable*]")(i).Value Then
```

I'm passing the column name to the function as variable (byVal *variable* as String), but I get an error. If I use the actual column name all works great. Should I be using a different syntax?

Comment: If you get an error, why don't you post the error message?

Comment: This reference may help you: http://superuser.com/questions/461075/dynamically-reference-a-named-table-column-via-cell-content-in-excel

Comment: Not tested but try: "Table4[" & variable & "]"

Comment: @LXG I get a RTE 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: @sous2817 - that seemed to do the trick! thanks

Comment: @CraigD Great!  for what it's worth, I posted it as an answer.  Feel free to upvote and / or accept it so that others know it worked and they can try it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to pass the string "variable" as the column header and not the string you're passing in from the method.  Try this, which will pass in the term you set in the variable "variable":

```
 "Table4[" & variable & "]"
```